# disabling mouse events on a wpf window and the user controls placed on it

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf window with many user controls on it. which event/function should i use to restrict the mouse input on the main window and the user controls it is hosting

Answer (score 7):

Try the [UIElement.IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) property.